# Шутки браузеров: криво работает php валидация?

Tags: php, webbrowser, opera

Я тестирую в основном сайт в Google Chrome (посл. версия), и только что заметил, что Opera (последняя версия) позволяет обойти ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЕ заполнить возраст. Просто игнорирует это поле и даже успешно отправляется форма и тп.

[Ссылка на форму](http://site.ru/registration)

А также наверно какие-то старые браузеры умудряются еще регать людей с НЕВОЗМОЖНЫМ значением пола, например.

Т.е. Опера в данном случае игнорит и `JS`, и `PHP` валидацию. Это вообще законна такая работа `PHP` и браузеров?

Использую rules:

```
$rules[] = array( 'gender', 'required', 'message' => 'Укажите пол' );
$rules[] = array( 'birthYear', 'required', 'message' => 'Укажите год рождения' );
$rules[] = array('gender', 'in', 'range' => array("f", "m", "?"), 'message' => 'Укажите пол.');
```

### Обновление

Добавил еще правило:

```
$rules[] = array( 'birthYear',
            'length',
            'min'=>$AGE_START,
            'max'=>$AGE_END,
            'tooShort' => 'Укажите год рождения',
            'tooLong' => 'Укажите год рождения',
        );
```

Опера перестала глючить.

Comment: привидите пример ваших правил в модели

Comment: и как вы сохраняете эту модель в контроллере

Comment: @korytoff ->save(), а есть еще способы?)

Comment: А как вы проставляете свойства модели? Возможно у вас есть значения по умолчанию?

Comment: напрямую $form->gender = $_POST['Form']['gender'];

Comment: Ну вот вам и ответ. Во-первых у вас Notice будет, во-вторых пустая строка в свойстве

Comment: ну ->attributes криво работает. Ну а что ответ? В хроме норм все, а опера по другому думает? предлагаете проверять на !empty() еще?

Comment: Да. Один браузер посылает не выбранный select, другой не посылает пообще. Получается в одном случае у вас пустая строка при обращении, а в другом случае приводится к null, что и дает ошибку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К вам на сервер от клиента (в данном случае браузер) могут прийти какие угодно данные. Валидация данных всегда должна быть на сервере помимо `JS`. Если у вас регистрация проходит даже без обязательных полей, значит у вас некорректный `PHP` код с валидацией.

### UPD

Лучше не обращаться к массиву `$_POST` напрямую. К тому же, в вашем выпадающем списке есть пустое значение. Один браузер его вам посылает, другой нет. Получается при обращении к `$_POST['Form']['gender']` у вас в одном случае строка пустая, в другом случае `null` (не факт, это моё предположение).

Проверьте `$_POST` массив в контроллере в разных браузерах:

```
var_dump($_POST); die();
```

Вам может помочь либо метод [saveAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#saveAttributes-detail), либо как минимум проверка на пустое значение:

```
if(isset($_POST['Form']['gender']) && $_POST['Form']['gender'] != '') {
    $form->gender = $_POST['Form']['gender'];
}
```

Comment: так она там есть.. что-то типа if ( $form->validate() ) {} Буду очень рад, если дело в МОЕМ коде.

Comment: @VitalikZ серверная часть не зависима от клиента, дело в Вашем php коде.

Comment: @VitalikZ обновил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Ок, все учту, спасибо!